Instantiated Enemies in Unity Following Player Overlap over Each Other
So for my top-down RPG, there are enemies in the overworld that will chase you if you get too close. (Like most turn-based RPGs nowadays.) The way it works is that the enemy spawner instantiates enemies at a random position at the start of the scene. That's not the problem, but the problem is the enemy overworld script itself.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyOverworld : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Details")]
    public BattleChar[] enemiesInArea;
    public int musicToPlay;
    public int maxAmountOfEnemies;
    public bool cannotFlee;
    public bool boss;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D m_Rigigbody;


    [Header("Overworld Details")]
    public float speed;
    Vector3 dirToPlayer;
    public bool chase = false;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!GameManager.instance.battleActive && chase)
        {
            dirToPlayer = (CameraController.instance.target.position - transform.position).normalized;

            if (dirToPlayer.magnitude > 0)
            {
                m_Rigigbody.MovePosition(Vector2.MoveTowards(m_Rigigbody.position, CameraController.instance.target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime));
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (!chase)
        {
            chase = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (chase)
        {
            float wait = 1;

            while (wait > 0)
            {
                wait -= Time.deltaTime;
            }

            chase = false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator StartBattleCo()
    {
        List<string> enemies = new();

        UIFade.instance.FadeToBlack();
        GameManager.instance.battleActive = true;
        int amount = 1;

        if (!boss)
        {
            amount = Random.Range(1, maxAmountOfEnemies);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            int enemy = Random.Range(0, enemiesInArea.Length);

            if (enemiesInArea[enemy].rareEnemy)
            {
                int chance = Random.Range(0, enemiesInArea[enemy].rarity * 10);

                if (chance <= enemiesInArea[enemy].rarity)
                {
                    enemies.Add(enemiesInArea[enemy].charName);
                }

                else
                {
                    i = i--;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                enemies.Add(enemiesInArea[enemy].charName);
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);

        BattleManager.instance.BattleStart(enemies.ToArray(), cannotFlee, boss, musicToPlay);

        UIFade.instance.FadeFromBlack();
        enemies.Clear();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}


When the enemy chases the player, they'll always overlap one another.
Each enemy has a solid capsule collider and a circle collider that's a trigger for the battle ienumerator. I've tried different methods like translating the position instead of using MoveTowards, but it's not working.

All of your enemies are following one player so they will eventually overlap. so you need to prevent these.
there are a few ways that ill mention 2
option 1- you are not using navmesh so you can just give enemies another collider with trigger disables so they cannot overlap.
option 2- you can implement a avoidance algorithm. my recommendation is the boid system.
- Set a minimum and maximum distance
- Get all enemies around you

- if they are closer than minimum then add the vector from other enemy to this to your move vector so it gets away from it.

- if they are further than maximum then add vector from this enemy to other enemy(inverse of previous one) to your move vector so you get closer to it.

normalize these vectors and multiply them with a number to make it feel better.
